# Apply solid principle without too much repetition of codes?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, architecture, solid-principles

I have tried to practice solid principle using some simple classes. Basically I want to grab a few fields from product A and product B to fit into a general class Product. And I want to be able to calculate the price based on currency.
I devide the `GetInUSDollars()` in separate as I want to leave the possibility for more currencies without changing the existing class. But try to use a single class for one function seems to create so much duplicates. Any direction I should go for to reduce the amount of duplicates?

```
public class ProductAData:IProduct
{
    public List<Product> GetAll()
    {
        return (from n in new ProductARepository().GetAll()
            select new Product { Id = n.Id, model = n.Model, Price = n.Price, Type = "ProductA" }).ToList();
    }
}
public class ProductADataInUSDollars: IProductInUSDollars
{
    public List<Product> GetInUSDollars()
    {
        return (from n in new PhoneCaseRepository().GetAll()
            select new Product { Id = n.Id, model= n.Model, Price = n.Price * 0.85, Type = "ProductA" }).ToList();
    }
}
```

There is another class that should fit into Product class as well.

```
public class ProductBCaseData : IProduct
{
    public List<Product> GetAll()
    {
        return (from n in new ProductBRepository().GetAll()
            select new Product { Id = n.Id, model= n.Model, Price = n.Price, Type = "ProductB" }).ToList();
    }
}

public class ProductBDataInUSDollars: IProductInUSDollars
{
    public List<Product> GetInUSDollars()
    {
        return (from n in new ProductBRepository().GetAll()
            select new Product { Id = n.Id, model= n.Model, Price = n.Price * 0.85, Type = "ProductB" }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You generally don't want a method for each currency, it breeds conditional logic where you will have to do some computation to determine the method to call (breaks Dependency Inversion Principal).

Instead you invert the control, and inject in the functionality you need masked behind a generic interface, i.e. something like:

```cs
public interface IProductInCurrency 
{
  IList<Product> GetInCurrency();
}

public class ProductBDataInUSDollars: IProductInCurrency
{
    public IList<Product> GetInCurrency()
    {
        return (from n in new ProductBRepository().GetAll()
            select new Product { Id = n.Id, model= n.Model, 
                Price = n.Price * 0.85, Type = "ProductB" }).ToList();
    }
}
```

You have masked the control though the interface, and the details of the implementation in the concrete. Your code always accepts the interface (constructor or method parameter) but you pass the concrete you need. i.e. Your implementation code works against the interface, in your example it acts like a converter, and you pass in the converter you want (Dollar implementation in this example, and you would re-implement IProductInCurrency for each currency you support).

In terms of solid, this way:

1. Single Responsibility is preserved. Each implementation of IProductInCurrency does one thing only - provide the product list in the correct currency.
2. Open-Closed Principal - it can be extended (add more currencies) by implementing a concrete for IProductInCurreny, but still closed for modification (they can't access the code that uses the interface).
3. Liskov - you can replace a concrete implementation with another implementation of IProductInCurrency, without changing the logic of the application.
4. Interface Segregation - We have interfaces for single operations, not one giant interface, so still good here.
5. Dependency inversion -the core of the example explanation I started with - no specific methods that bleed conditional logic (e.g. GetInUSDollars() would break this principal). Instead we invert the control and inject in dependencies where needed.

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot understand how it  decreases of duplicate code. Could you clarify, pls. Thanks!

Comment: @BlackSpy I thought about using DI as well, but could you explain further how this helps to reduce duplicates? Seems we still need to write the same code again and again for different currencies.

Comment: SOLID principles won't result in reduced code on its own. You need to apply DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) alongside it.

Comment: @BlackSpy That sounds good, could you explain further how to apply Solid principle without losing dry principle in this case?

Comment: Generally, the moment you find yourself in a copy and paste situation (even if you make changes afterwards) - avoid the temptation. Go back to your design, consider how to refactor to allow for the differences in execution scenarios and ensure you aren't duplicating logic in multiple places, then do that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at principles and your solution I think the following thoughts would be somewhat applicable:

#### [Single-responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)

You didn't want one god object that handles all currencies - so you went ahead and separated classes by currency. You however ended up duplicating code, which can be argued to contradict the principle by introducing multiple objects with the same responsibility.

#### [Open–closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle)

It's hard to say whether you extend your objects rather than modify their behaviour with switches in your code base as we only see interface implementations and not much else. I would say you're on the right track here as we don't see one class with a `switch` of multiple currency exchange rates.

#### [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Hard to say based on code base sample - you seem to not depend on any higher-level abstractions (`BaseCurrency`, `BaseProduct` etc) here. On the contrary you define pretty specific interfaces which imply concrete implementation.

#### [Interface segregation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle)

I think you've got this one so I'll skip over.

#### [Dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)

This is the meat of my answer. I believe you currently do not depend on anything but your concrete exchange rates. Rates are definitely not fixed constants and change multiple times a day - so hardcoding these sounds undesirable.
If you however elect to inject an abstraction of Currency in your code - it should allow you to actually collapse these branches into logical blocks of code that each do their respective things: fetching data (you've got it) mapping DB entities to DTOs (I assume you're doing exactly that) and finally, applying business logic such as currency conversion. I would say you can take it a step further and Introduce a `BaseProduct` class and instead of hardcoding Type into each - opt for derived classes such as `class ProductA: Product {}` and `class ProductB:Product {}` - you then woulddepend on abstractions everywhere else and would be able to act differently on each one without consulting the Type property each time (I'd leave that exercise for you to complete though)

With the above I would suggest a structure like below:

```cs
#region Currencies definitions
class Currency { 
    public double ExchangeRate {get;set;} // suppose this defines relation of a given currency to "base" currency your application uses internally
    public string Tag {get;set;} // just some means to identify it. you can use numeric Ids or anything else you deisre

    public Currency(double exchangeRate, string tag) {
        ExchangeRate = exchangeRate; 
        Tag = tag;
    }
}
class AUD : Currency // you don't have to define classes with hardcoded values, but I'd do it for example
{
    public AUD() : base(1.5, "AUD") {}
}
class NZD : Currency
{
    public NZD() : base(1.6, "NZD") { }
}
#endregion 

#region Product classes stubs - yours will differ
// I'm assuming your repository comes back with something like this - your exact case would be slightly different
class ProductEntity { 
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Model {get;set;}
    public double Price {get;set;}
    public string Currency {get;set;} // let's say your DB has a field that indicates what currency your price is in
}

class Product // depending on whether PoductType changes behaviour of the application, you might want to derive a couple classes based on that and override behaviours in respective subclasses rather than here
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string model { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
#endregion

void Main()
{   
    var currencies = new Dictionary<string, Currency> { { "AUD", new AUD() }, { "NZD", new NZD()}}; // you either hard-code these or read rates from the database. Using Dictionary is optional, I just found it easier to map later on

    var products = new List<ProductEntity>(); // suppose, this is your new ProductBRepository().GetAll() call

    var result = (from n in products
            select new Product
            {
                Id = n.Id,
                model = n.Model,
                Price = currencies[n.Currency].ExchangeRate * n.Price, // a note of caution - you haven't specified the ORM you use or how you get your data, if ProductBRepository().GetAll() is a list it's probably all good, but EntityFramework might complain it's unable to translate this into SQL when building query for you
                Type = "ProductB"
            }).ToList();
}
```

It's pretty high level and you definitely will need to tweak it to your needs, but hopefully it'd provide you with general concept of where I'm getting at.

**UPD**
I also just noticed you use two repositories for different types of products, which again is somewhat undesirable (unless products are actually different entities altogether). The `Product` class refactoring I suggested you to go through would help here: by merging the two into a more generic `ProductRepository` and apply Liskov substitution principle so your code does not need to depend on specific repo

Comment: That is very helpful, another answer mentioned I seem to violate the DRY principle, I wonder what's your thoughts on that.

Comment: I don't disagree with that - as I pointed out in the `Single Responsibility` paragraph you seem to have multiple nearly identical blocks that are meant to do the same thing. You will find it harder to maintain over time, especially if your logic is more complicated. For potential solutions consider `Strategy` pattern if you find your logic is complex